# Finding range of given function.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions

This was a question which came in my test. I didn't give the test. Some students were discussing how hard it was. I gave it a try at home.

**Question**

> Find the no. of different values functions takes.
>   $$f(x)=\bigg\lfloor \frac{x^2}{2005} \bigg\rfloor$$
>   Here $x \in [1,2005]$ and $x \in \mathbb N$

**The way I tried this question:**

> I assumed that (which will eventually turn out to be wrong) this function would produce some repeated values in starting i.e. for $x\in [1,44]$ the function will give $0$, 44 times. And then the function would start giving values which won't repeat itself. We need to find the point upto which the function repeats the values. As lets say last repeated value it gave was(mere random example) $405$ at $x=900$. So answer would be $(2005-900)+405$. As the before $x=900$ function will give values from $[0,405]$ and after that the remaining numbers will give different values as they won't repeat any values they give.

**How is my assumption wrong:**

> Actually the function gives some repeated values in the start and after wards it starts to give a values which are repeated and unrepeated both intermingled in each other. And after that some values skip, some repeat and some neither skip nor repeat i.e. come exactly once.

Thank you for any help provided. Please help me solving this question.

**Post script:** Also this question had 3 minutes time alloted to it. We had to find the number of proper divisors of the number of different values function takes.
This hidden piece contains answer.

> And the answer was 2. Now if number of proper divisor is 2, the number is obviously a square of a prime number. Isn't that a big hint? I don't see how.

Comment: Just an observation: $0\leq  f(x+1)-f(x)\leq 2$

Comment: @Lozenges -that is true. But how will that help?

Comment: @LoveInvariants The number of divisors when $x=405$ are more than $2$, can you check that? It doesn't agree with your answer.

Comment: @Rick -No no. That was a mere random example. That isn't true. And 2 is the no of proper divisors of the answer.

Comment: I checked with a calculator, $x= 405$ gives $f(x) =81$ and it has more than $1$divisors, I mean it ain't prime.

Comment: Similarly for $x =605 , f(x) =182$, again not a prime. Can you check that please?

Comment: The answer (computer assisted ) is $1504$. That has more than $2$ proper divisors. On the other hand $501=2005-1504$ has $2$ proper divisors.

Comment: @Lozenges- 501 has 3 proper divisors. It might be 1369 or 1681 if answer is indeed 2. Maybe the answer was wrong. But we surely need to find the process to solve this in 3 minutes or so time. Answer could be changed if someone asks the teacher  to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$x^2-(x-1)^2=2x-1$$
Also when $\frac{x^2}{2005}\gt\frac{(x-1)^2}{2005}+1$ we cannot proceed to have two $x$ with the same functional value. This is because $\lfloor y+1\rfloor\gt\lfloor y\rfloor$. So we can then find the range of such $x$ values by using the first identity as
$$\frac{x^2}{2005}\gt\frac{(x-1)^2}{2005}+1$$
$$x^2\gt(x-1)^2+2005$$
$$x^2-(x-1)^2\gt2005$$
$$2x-1\gt2005$$
$$2x\gt2006$$
$$x\gt1003$$
So for all $x\gt1003$ we must have every $x$ value with a unique functional value as previously mentioned. For all $x\le1003$ there may not be a unique functional value, but it's guaranteed that every possible output value has occurred between $0$ and $f(1003)$ because of the fact that the difference between floored terms is less than $1$.
$$f(1003)=\left\lfloor\frac{1003^2}{2005}\right\rfloor=501$$
Hence the total number of different values the function takes is
$$502+2005-1003=1504$$

Comment: I see it anyways. I will put it here for anyone who doesn't see. There can't be any skips if the consecutive values who difference is being taken is less than 1. As to skip a no n, the function should've a value less than n and next one greater than n+1 whose difference will be eventually more than 1 which occurs never before 1003.